# Reversing Integer Value

Tags: java, integer, reverse

I cannot figure this out. This is for homework. I need to create a method that reverses an integer that is passed to it. I've now been able to fix the outofBounds error in the `for` loop thanks to everyone's input. The integer that is passed into the method can be of any length. And I have to return an integer instead of an array or string. But now I get an 'Unresolved compilation problem: Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this token' on the `int u = backInt[];` line. But I have no idea what to put in the []'s. I haven't been able to find a way to convert an Integer array to an integer so I can pass the integer back, so I'm lost. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
public static int reverseIt(int x){

    int y = String.valueOf(x).length();
    int[] backInt = new int [y];
    for(int z = 0; z < y; z++){
        x %=10;
        backInt[z] = x;
        x /= 10;
    }
            int u = backInt[];
            return u;


    return -1;

}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You're running this code on the computer too early. Try running it on paper first. Keep track of the current value of each variable and trace through the program one line at a time. Start with a two-digit value for `x`. You should soon see several problems with your current algorithm.

Comment: @Michael no, it didn't look like you were. As far as I could see, the only thing you did wrong was forget the [homework] tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with `z=0` and end with `z=y`. That's `y+1` times through the loop, but your array is correctly only `y` elements long, so the exception occurs on the last iteration of the loop when you try to write to the nonexistent element. By that time, though, `x` should already be zero because you've processed all `y` digits, so your stopping condition should be `z<y` instead of `z<=y`.

Answer (score 1):

You're going too far in your loop. It should be:

```
for(int z = 0; z < y; z++) {
```

...instead.

Take the input `12` as an example. It's two characters long, so `backInt` has a length of 2. When you go through the loop, you're iterating through values of `z` of `0`, `1`, and `2`. What's the value of `backInt[2]` when `backInt` only has two elements in it?

*Edit:* Your code will also break for, say, 2147483646, because your resulting integer will be too large for the Integer type. But that's beside the point here.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are 0-indexed. What that means is that if you do `int[] arr = new int[10]`, you create an integer array that can hold ten `ints`, and the first int is stored in `arr[0]`, the second in `arr[1]`, and the last in `arr[10-1]`, which is `arr[9]`.

To fix your code, change `z <= y` to `z < y`. In the future, just remember that if you create an array for `n` objects, then you can access them by `arr[0], arr[1]... arr[n-1]`, but accessing `arr[n]` will throw an `OutOfBounds` exception.